# `<textarea>` ignores `width` and `height` attributes

Tags: html, css

How do I set the height and width of a textarea in HTML?

They seem to be ignored and the default values of `rows` and `cols` are used to determine the size of the `<textarea>` instead.

I am viewing [this page](https://www.jamescobban.net/BlogPost.php) with Firefox 62.

```css
    textarea   {
  font-family: serif;
  text-align: left;
  border-top: 3px solid black;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #808080;
  border-right: 3px solid #808080;
  }

    div.row { white-space: nowrap; }

    label.column1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0px 3px 0px 3px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  float:  left;
  width:  15em;
  }
```

```html
<div class="row" id="blogMsgRow">
      <label class='column1' for='message'>    
     Message:
      </label>
      <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="[enter message]"
          height='50%' width='80%'></textarea>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you mean `style="width: 80%; height: 50%;"`? `<textarea>`s don’t have `width` and `height` attributes.

Comment: Why not set the width in CSS?

percentile height won't work unless you give the parent element a fixed height.

Comment: You can use rows and cols attribute instead of height and width. Should be a fixed number value like how many rows and how many cols you wanted to size the textarea.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the `width` and `height` in the `css`.
`<textarea>` tag doesn’t have `width` and `height` attributes.
Percentage `height` won't work unless the parent element, `div`, has a fixed height.

```
textarea {
    font-family: serif;
    text-align: left;
    border-top: 3px solid black;
    border-left: 3px solid black;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #808080;
    border-right: 3px solid #808080;
    width: 80%;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Note: a percentile height won't work unless the parent element has a fixed height. But a fixed height like in this example will.

Comment: @trattles, the parent of `textarea` is `div` tag. So percentage width will work. `height` couldn't work because `div` doesn't have fixed height as you said.

Comment: Thank you for all of the suggestions.  I changed the HTML to:

Comment: @JamesCobban, So your issue fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestions. I changed the HTML to:

```
<div class="row" id="blogMsgRow">
  <label class='column1' for='message' id="msgLabel">
    Message:
  </label>
  <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="[enter message]"
       rows=15 style="width=80%;"></textarea>
</div>
```

But the width was still ignored.  So I tried setting the width using Javascript:

```
        var msgLabel    = document.getElementById('msgLabel');
        var textwidth   = window.innerWidth - msgLabel.offsetWidth - 10;
        element.style.width = textwidth + 'px';
        alert("97: set element.style.width=" + textwidth + 'px');
        element.focus();    // make it the current input element
        element.select();   // select all text
```

This solves the problem.

I do not want to set the cols and rows specifications because they depend upon the font dimensions. And cols is a rather stupid unit to use with a variable width font.